# Jquery to javascript keypress event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following in jquery code:

```
$(document).keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {

    }
});
```

How can I make this into javascript so I do not need to load jquery everyime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
document.onkeypress = function (e) {
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if(keyCode == 13) {

    }
    ...
}
```

Reading:

- http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html

Comment: And `e = e || window.event;`. http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html might be interesting to read as well.

Comment: @David19801: Some browsers use the `event` parameter passed to the function, and some use `window.event`.  jQuery makes cross browser stuff easy by taking care of that for you.